# Java Multithreading: Informix 12.10 - Could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row

Tags: java, multithreading, informix

We are using informix 12.10 version. We are deleting multiple rows of records across 54 tables from Java batch. we are using callable strategy in Multi-threading.
Please refer to the below code:
SampleImpl.java:

```
Callable<Integer> callable=null;
List<Callable<Integer>> taskList = null;
List<Future<Integer>> futureList = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : datas.entrySet()){
    callable = new Callable<Integer>(){
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return sampleDel.callSqlDelete();
        }
    };
    taskList.add(callable);
}
```

SampleDaoImpl:

```
public void callSqlDelete(){
    Statement stmt = null;
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT");
    stmt.addBatch("DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE col1 IN(select from tableAAA where id=101)");
    stmt.addBatch("DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE col1 IN(select from tableAAA where id=101)"");
    int delCnt[] = stmt.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
}
```

In our java code we have already set lock mode to wait to infinite time interval but still we are getting the below exception:

```
    java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Could not do a physical-order read to fetch next row.
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.executeBatch(IfxStatement.java:1650)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.StatementProxyFactory.invoke(StatementProxyFactory.java:272)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at com.sample.samplereport.dao.impl.SampleDAOPurgeImpl.processDelByStmts(SampleDAOPurgeImpl.java:1305)
        at com.sample.samplereport.util.SamplePlSqlDeleter.callSqlDelete(SamplePlSqlDeleter.java:58)
        at com.sample.samplereport.dao.impl.SampleDAOPurgeImpl$1.call(SampleDAOPurgeImpl.java:298)
        at com.sample.samplereport.dao.impl.SampleDAOPurgeImpl$1.call(SampleDAOPurgeImpl.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Please help on the above issue?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of error it is usually helpful to see the ISAM error code that the Informix engine also provides. This gives more information on why the operation failed, in this case why it was unable to read the next row. One way to get the ISAM error is to set the environment variable APPENDISAM in the client Java environment. There may well be other ways to achieve this as well. FYI you can find further information in the Informix JDBC Driver documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_040.htm

For this problem I suspect the ISAM error may be 143 "deadlock detected." This results when one thread needs to wait on a lock that is held by another thread which in turn is waiting on a lock already held by the first thread. Since you have set lock mode to wait without a timeout the result would be the threads waiting forever so the server returns a deadlock error instead.

To help avoid the problem you should check that row level locking is used in preference to page level locking for TABLE1 and TABLE2. You may also want to check the isolation level used. If using Repeatable Read isolation or the database is mode ANSI then the select statement used in the sub-query will place a lock on every row it considers although these should be minimized if there is an index on the "id" column.

At an application code level deadlock is frequently handled by rolling back the transaction and repeating it.

Comment: The ISAM error from the server is usually attached as a nested SQLException.  Calling getCause() should reveal the underlying problem which as @simon-riddle notes is likely a deadlock detected as multiple threaded deletes are trying to delete the same rows and are waiting forever on each others locks.